# How to force Skype for Business as a front-end?

Tags: skype, lync, lync-2013

I use (as an end-user) Lync 2013 with a Lync 2013 Server infrastructure.

A recent Windows update brought Skype for Business as a replacement/alternative for the Lync 2013 client front-end. I installed it and upon launching it informed me that the Lync administrators have enforced the use of Lync as a front-end and the installation program kindly asked me to restart the client to have Lync, instead of Skype for Business. However

- I had the option to say "Later" (which I chose)
- **Skype for Business started, connected and worked flawlessly**

I rebooted and upon the launch of Skype for Business I now get the Lync 2013 front-end (without any questions asked).

How can I recover Skype for Business -- it is obviously possible to run it since it has been running after the first install, I believe that there will be a magical registry switch which would enable one or the other (bypassing the server check).

<sub>NOTE: I am aware why the Lync client has been forced and all the consequences to bypass a setting enforced at server level (this comment is to avoid answers around the ethical and workload related warnings ("*If they did it there is a reason*" -- I welcome the technical issues which will also be useful for the Lync administrators)</sub>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a good explanation of the process at https://chentiangemalc.wordpress.com/2015/04/21/force-skype-for-business-ui/

The steps are (some verbatim from the referenced site):

- change the registry entry `EnableSkypeUI` at `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\Lync` so that it has the value `00 00 00 01`
- ensure that subsequent restarts of Skype for Business do not override this by denying your user account `Set Value` permission on that registry folder. Do this by right clicking Lync folder in registry and select `Permissions –> Advanced –> Add`, then select `Advanced permissions` and `Deny Set Value`.